# Old Style fan system bone/armiture set up

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, constraints

[image]

I need to animate this old style Indian fan. The crank shaft would need rotate 360 and the flat plane (aka the canvas fan) would need to sway back and forth.

[image]

I've set up the bone structure. From what i understand is that i can use the inverse kinematics restrict the moment along the z and x axis and only allow the pivot along the y axis. But the main big bone as to follow the movements of either smaller bones on the cam shaft and on the flat canvas fan. Im not sure how to allow it to follow each with out deforming the other.

Comment: I think something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1GmLAVeySY) would work

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me :)